# CORS Ajax post with Jetty/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to do a cross-domain POST with jQuery using CORS, but after the OPTIONS request is sent (and responded to), the POST doesn't happen. My request/response filters are shown below. My jQuery post code is also shown. It looks like the response has the proper CORS response headers, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
var params = {};
params.data = myPostData;
params.headers = {
  'x-pingother' : 'pingpong'
};
$.ajax(params);
```

Request Header

```
OPTIONS /my/service/url HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:9876
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-pingother
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9876
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-pingother
Content-Length: 703
Content-Type: application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Allow: OPTIONS,POST
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Jan 2013 13:46:51 EST
Server: Jetty(6.1.25)
```

I'm running automated tests from a local server (JSTestDriver) that connects to a web server running on a different port. The web server runs on 8080 and the page making the request runs on 9876.

Comment: Have you tried just sending an XHR POST, skipping jQuery and the OPTIONS request? This does look like it should work as far as I can tell. I guess the post doesn't happen, but there's also no warning about attempted cross-domain requests?

Comment: I think it's a jquery issue, but not sure yet. When I remote the content-type I get a media not supported error, but the post is attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding the response headers as specified in

[jQuery CORS request not working when sending Range request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822709/jquery-cors-request-not-working-when-sending-range-request)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to explicitly tell jQuery to enable cors?

```
$.support.cors = true;
```